# Show $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}^*\quad 3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge 2 (\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a})$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^*$ Show that :

$$3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge 2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^*$

let $t=\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}$ , we've :
$$
\begin{aligned}
3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge 2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) &\iff
3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}-2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)\\
&\iff t^{2}-2t+1\geq 0\\
&\iff \left(t-1\right)^{2}\geq 0
\end{aligned}$$
since $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\quad (t-1)^{2}\geq 0$ holds then also  $$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}^*\quad 3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge 2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) $$ holds

Am i right ? is there any other ways

Comment: i think your way is right, i have posted another one

Comment: @Educ Just asking. Maybe I'm wrong. Could it more general if we just prove $$3+x^2+y^2\geq 2(x+y),$$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^*$?

Answer (score 2):

We have: $1+\dfrac{a^2}{b^2} \ge \dfrac{2a}{b}, 1+\dfrac{b^2}{a^2} \ge \dfrac{2b}{a}$. Adding these we have the desire inequality. Thus the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 1):

your inequality is equivalent to $${\frac { \left( {a}^{2}-ab+{b}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{{b}^{2}{a}^{2}}}\geq 0$$ and this is true for all $$a,b>0$$

Comment: its true for all $a,b\ne0$

Comment: but the original problem demands $$a,b>0$$

Comment: well, you've solved it for a larger range then

Comment: The original problem asks for $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R^*$, which often stands for $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, thus $a<0$ or $b<0$ should also be considered.

Comment: Agreeable solution. It is valid for all $ab\ne 0$

Comment: This is hardly different from the solution posted by OP. Just plug $t=a/b+b/a$ in $(t-1)^2\ge0$.

Comment: yes this is another solution by me, is this forbidden?

Comment: I mean this is _not_ another solution. It's exactly the same solution posted by OP.